# Ubuntu 19.10 completely freezes

Tags: 19.10, bug-reporting

I have Ubuntu 19.10 installed on my AMD system. The system often hangs beyond any recovery and nothing works, no key inputs, no mouse, even the screen is frozen. I think it is something to do with Chrome, but can't say for sure.

I have tried removing any extra linux-headers but it did not really help.

The only way to recover after is to switch off the power ad reboot.

Comment: I experienced the same. Turned out is was a faulty mother board.

Comment: @vanadium I doubt that because I used Ubuntu 19.04 and 18.04 before that without any issues whatsoever.

Comment: Run `dmesg -w` in a terminal window and set the window to remain on front. Thus you could see kernel messages shortly before the system freezes.

Comment: and you could also send the output to a text file that will survive reboots. this seems to work for me and updates when I remove and insert an SSD drive

    'dmesg -w > $HOME/temp/dmsg_cust.log'